# integer to char array conversion in C

Tags: c, arrays, integer, char

I have the code below. I would like to modify the first three characters (`001`) of `packet_received` by increasing the value by one (*002*). However, I get the following output when I run the code:

```
Hop_network = 001 
new Hop_network = 2 
packet_received = 2
```

what I would like to see is:

> packet_received = 002456

How can I do it? The code works fine when the first characters are not 0s, and the receid message does not have to start with 0s all the time. Thank you for the answers.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char Hop_network[4];
    char packet_received[]= "001456";
    int Hop_increaser;

    Hop_network[0] = packet_received[0];
    Hop_network[1] = packet_received[1];
    Hop_network[2] = packet_received[2];
    Hop_network[3] = '\0';
    printf("Hop_network = %s\n", Hop_network);

    Hop_increaser = atoi(Hop_network);
    Hop_increaser = Hop_increaser + 1;
    sprintf(Hop_network, "%d", Hop_increaser);
    printf("new Hop_network = %s\n", Hop_network);

    packet_received[0] = Hop_network[0];
    packet_received[1] = Hop_network[1];
    packet_received[2] = Hop_network[2];
    printf("packet_received = %s\n", packet_received);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the width specifier to sprintf to left-justify the number.

```
sprintf(Hop_network, "%03d", Hop_increaser);
```

This means "left-justify with zeroes to width 3".

The documentation for all format-specifiers can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/